# Getting rows which have a certain revision_status

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql and I have two tables:

**Product Table:**

```
| id | name      | prices | revision_id |
|----|-----------|--------|-------------|
| 1  | Produkt 1 | 10     | 1           |
| 2  | Produkt 1 | 4      | 2           |
| 3  | Produkt 1 | 2      | 3           |
| 4  | Product 2 | 42     | 4           |
| 5  | Produkt 2 | 43     | 5           |
| 6  | Produkt 3 | 78     | 6           |
```

Each product has had price changes. That is why the name is still the same, but the products have a different price.

**Revisions Table:**

```
| id | revision_status |
|----|-----------------|
| 1  | 1               |
| 2  | 0               |
| 3  | 0               |
| 4  | 1               |
| 5  | 0               |
| 6  | 1               |
```

Inside the revision table, `0` indicates an open change, not approved change. `1` indicates - closed - an approved change.

***Expected Result:***

```
| id | name      | prices | revision_id | revision_status |
|----|-----------|--------|-------------|-----------------|
| 1  | Produkt 1 | 10     | 1           | 1               |
| 2  | Produkt 1 | 4      | 2           | 0               |
| 3  | Produkt 1 | 2      | 3           | 0               |
| 4  | Product 2 | 42     | 4           | 1               |
| 5  | Produkt 2 | 43     | 5           | 0               |
```

Basically I want all products that have revisions - a `revision_status` of 0 on it, to see which products actually have revisions.

For example.: `Product 3` does not have any price changes, so it should not appear in the final result.

I tried the following:

```
select *
  from product
  JOIN revisions 
    on product.revisions_id = revisions.id 
 ORDER 
    BY product.name
```

However, I still get `Product 3` in my table and I am not sure how to get all products that have a revision_status of 0 on it.

I highly appreciate your replies!

Comment: I don't understand why all the products have the same name!?!

Comment: your question is not clear  ..

Comment: @Strawberry Basically the products have the same name, but the price got changed. A revision ID of 1 indicates that it is approved and a revision ID of 0 indicates that it is on hold.

Comment: @scaisEdge I  updated my question details. Basically, my question is not about the Product name, but the price change. The revision table tracks, which products have been changed. The revision_status shows which products have been approved and which not.

Comment: Isn't there a typo in the product names (product 2 vs produkt 2)?

Comment: So why is the revision status in a separate table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my interpretation you are looking for the products which have more than one revision. Filtering only on `revision_status = 0` would not produce your expected result. The following query may answer your question (looking for those products which have more than 1 revision):

```
SELECT *
FROM product AS p
INNER JOIN revisions AS r ON p.revision_id = r.id 
WHERE p.name IN (
  SELECT p.name
  FROM product AS p
  INNER JOIN revisions AS r ON p.revision_id = r.id 
  GROUP BY p.name
  HAVING COUNT(r.revision_status) > 1)
ORDER BY p.name
```

This would produce your expected result. See example at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64fbd1/9).

Comment: Thx for your reply! I just found that I also have some`revision_status` with `null`. Any suggestions how to include them also?

Comment: Try to replace the `HAVING COUNT(...)` part to `HAVING COUNT(IFNULL(r.revision_status, 0)) > 1`. This way if a product has multiple revision statuses and also some of them are null, they are also counted. See an example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3cc6549/1), note revision id 5 has a null value and also counted.